# How to Deep link from Website to android App

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking

I have a website that is mainly used by mobile users. I want to link from the website to a separate app, which should then open on the phone (the app is already installed)

For the app, I have entered the following scheme:

```
 <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="alfix_smart" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="domain.com" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_HOST" value="www.domain.com" />
```

how can I now link a button of a website to the app? What do I have to do for that? Unfortunately, I have no idea.

I hope you can help me

Comment: I'd recommend using a service like branch.io or the like.  Doing it by hand and keeping everything working between Android, iOS, and the weird formats required by Chrome is a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

• If you want to handle deep linking in both Android and iOS, it is recommended to use [Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/). With `Dynamic Links`, you treat on all platforms such as Android, iOS and web in a similar way. It seamlessly transits users from your mobile website to the equivalent content within your app. To see its usage example, refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive).

• If you want to handle deep linking in Android only (and the app is already installed as you mentioned), in simplest approach ([Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)), you can introduce your `Activity` as a handler of specific pattern `URL`s and pass the desired parameters as `URL` query params.

To see its usage example in details, refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

**In AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://example.com" -->
        <data android:host="example.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://www.example.com" -->
        <data android:host="www.example.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**In YourActivity.java:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (data.getQueryParameter("some_param") != null && data.getQueryParameter("some_param").isNotEmpty()) {

            String param = data.getQueryParameter("some_param");
            // do what you want to do with param
        }
    }
}
```

**Your html snippet:**

```
<a href="https://example.com?some_param=some_value">Click Me!</a>
```